# How to pickup an element, which will call function in this function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've got an HTML element, which looks like this:

```
    <a onclick="doSomething()">Do something!</a>
```

And I need to inside this called function pick up parent element which called it. Something like this:

```
    function doSomething() {
            var $parentElement = this.parents('.theClass');
    }
```

Comment: What is the parent element for the <a> element? Is it a div or a span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `this` as argument to your `doSomething`, so define it like this:

```
function doSomething(elem) {
   var $parentElement = $(elem).parents('.theClass');
}
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="doSomething(this)">Do something!</a>
```

Now, the argument contains the element which you can wrap it with jQuery and transverse the DOM as you like it.

---

However I wouldn't recommend using inline-js, especially after you've included jQuery.

You would be much better off using this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var $parentElement = $(this).parents('.theClass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .[parentNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317) notation in pure javascript.

```
<a onclick="doSomething(this)">Do something!</a>

function doSomething(elem) {
    var parent = document.getElementByID(elem).parentNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="doSomething.call(this)">Do something!</a>
```

This will correctly transfer the `this` into the function.